# Overfull \hbox when inserting citation in blockquote

Tags: biblatex, xetex, warnings

I am inserting a `\blockquote` in my document but when adding a citation at the end of it (with a `\hfill` to make it right-aligned), I get an `Overfull \hbox`.

This only happens using `xelatex` which I'm using. The badbox appears/disappears as I activate/comment out the `geometry` package with all the related margin definitions. Is there a way to tell Latex to right align the citation without going to a new line? Why isn't it just filling the available space? I don't understand what is going on.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry} % <--- this one provokes the overfull \hbox
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber,style=authoryear,firstinits=true,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibl.bib}
@book{seiler,
  title={Possession as an Operational Dimension of Language},
  author={Seiler, Hansjakob},
  publisher={TÃŒbingen: Gunter Narr},
  year={1983}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibl.bib}

\begin{document}\doublespacing
\lipsum[2]

\blockquote{\singlespacing Semantically, the domain of POSSESSION can be described as bio-cultural. It is the relationship between a human being, his kinsmen, his body parts, his material belongings, his cultural and intellectual products. In a more extended view, it is the relationship between parts and whole of an organism.\hfill \parencite[4]{seiler}}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
bio-cul\-tu\-ral.
```

then it can be hyphenated without an overful box. With the  option `draft` you can see the problem with this word. As an alternative activate the german shortcuts and write `bio"=cultural`. It is a limitation of TeX that words with a hyphen cannot have other hyphenation points if not specified. Here is a preamble how I would solve the problem. I always use babel:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside,draft]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[ngerman,italian]{babel}% the last one is active
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasitalian{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits=true,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\blockquote{\singlespacing Semantically, the domain of POSSESSION can be described as 
    bio"=cultural. It is the relationship between a human being, his kinsmen, his body 
    parts, his material belongings, his cultural and intellectual products. In a more 
    extended view, it is the relationship between parts and whole of an organism.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, but why are they called german shortcuts? And where should I add that you posted? I thought it was inside a `\hyphenation{}` but it's not working...

Comment: We have a _lot_ of two words combined with a  hyphen. An old problem for german texts.  `polyglossia` has an option for the german shortcuts

Comment: Interesting :) But I was wondering, could you include the code for applying the hyphenation? No need for the whole MWE, but I'd like to see how the relevant part is coded.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: So this doesn't work with polyglossia?

Comment: For polyglossia it is the option babelshorthands. But I do not know how diffrent languages can be used in polyglossia. However, babel is better

Comment: I understand, but I'd like to stick to `polyglossia` for the time being. Would you mind showing a solution for it instead? I suppose the babelshorthands work for German, but I'm not using German in my document, so it kind of feels like a hack? Anyway, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What you need is `\penalty\@M-\hskip\z@skip` in the text instead of the single  `-`. However, for german the `"` is an active character and `"= ` is then defined with the above definition.  You have to decide to define an own command, e.g. `\def\A{\penalty\@M-\hskip\z@skip}` or making `"` active and defining `\def"={...}` or simply using `low-tem\-pe\-ra\-ture` if you have only some words with a hyphen in your document.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help and time, I really do appreciate it. But since nothing was working for me, not to mention that it didn't seem to be worth all the trouble, I decided to get rid of the `\blockquote{}` command completely and use [a different approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294929/4778). I suppose it was that command that created problems with the automatic hyphenation that Latex does.

Comment: No, it has _nothing_ to do with `\blockquote` it is a matter of formatting! `bio-cultural` was the last word in the first line. That's all. Change the margin aof `\blockquote` and it will work, too.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching and testing, I finally decided to get rid of the `\blockquote{}` command and use a custom one to achieve the same result after finding something similar in my searches. Needless to say, everything works flawlessly as one would expect from Latex.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber,style=authoryear,firstinits=true,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibl.bib}
@book{seiler,
  title={Possession as an Operational Dimension of Language},
  author={Seiler, Hansjakob},
  publisher={TÃŒbingen: Gunter Narr},
  year={1983}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibl.bib}

\newcommand\myquote[1]{%
\par
\begingroup
\leftskip4em
\rightskip\leftskip
\singlespacing
\noindent
#1
\par
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}\doublespacing
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa.

\myquote{Semantically, the domain of POSSESSION can be described as bio-cultural. It is the relationship between a human being, his kinsmen, his body parts, his material belongings, his cultural and intellectual products. In a more extended view, it is the relationship between parts and whole of an organism.\hfill \parencite[4]{seiler}}

Nulla malesuada por itor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tin- cidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellen- tesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ip- sum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum.
\end{document}
```